# Debug angular app in Intellij with chrome under windows

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm looking quite a while for a solution to debug a angular app in intellij using chrome on Windows.

At the moment I'm not able to get a debugger attached to chrome. I tried starting chreme with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` and a lot of other solutions.

Currently I'm using IntelliJ 2020.2 and Chrome 86.

Does anyone have a solution for windows?

Answer (score 9):

I am on Mac, but I think this might be helpful for you as it resolved my issue.

The workaround is to go to:

> Settings -> Tools -> Web Browsers and Preview

Edit the Chrome entry, and put `--remote-allow-origins=*` in the Command line options.

[image: Steps]

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/120faod/comment/jdk82yz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 7):

If you're having the error:
Please ensure that the browser was started successfully with remote debugging port opened. Port cannot be opened if Chrome having the same User Data Directory is already launched

Try removing this file:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.2\options\other.xml
```

If that didn't work, in addition to the above, remove this file:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.2\options\web-browsers.xml
```

As always remember to take backups of your files.

Comment: in 2023/03, this path worked for me in windows
`%APPDATA%\JetBrains\WebStorm2022.2\options`
The ~ syntax did nothing useful, just opened a new browser window

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps described in [Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging):

- run `npm start` to start your app
- create the [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration, specify your server URL there (`http://localhost:4200/` or whatever it looks like)
- Set the breakpoints in your code.
- debug the configuration above

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/

Comment: I tryed the solution described above, but did not get it running.

When I start the debug configuration, a chrome instance is opened with a tab that says "crashed".

Also in the Event Log in Intellij I get the message:

07:02 Waiting for connection to localhost:57914. 
   Please ensure that the browser was started successfully with remote debugging port opened. 
   Port cannot be opened if Chrome having the same User Data Directory is already launched.

Comment: hmm... Does look like the IDE issue. what OS are you on? what is a result of starting Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port` option?

Comment: I'm using windows 10. Where do I have to set the - - remote-debug-port option and which port is the right? 9222?

Comment: Hi @lena just tryed with the `--remote-debugging-port=9222` still no luck. The debugger does not attach to any chrome process. Chrome sessions started by intellij are all broken/crashed.